# npm Error: ENOENT, chmod. what's the deal?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install an npm module I just published

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bg-di122/src/bin/brain-games.js
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bg-di122/src/bin/brain-games.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

So what's the deal?

Comment: Which NPM module ?

Comment: bg-di122  https://www.npmjs.com/package/bg-di122